# How to add a table row with P5.js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

```
<table class="table">
   <tbody id="user_table" class="user_table">

   </tbody>
</table>
```

I am loading my data from fire base and want to create a table with P5. This is what I have tried.

```
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        var tr = createElement("tr");
            tr.parent("user_table");
            tr.class("success");
        var td_1 = createElement("td");
            td_1.html(player_data[i][0]);
            td_1.class('myclass-td');
            td_1.parent("success");
        var td_2 = createElement("td");
            td_2.html(player_data[i][1]);
            td_2.class('myclass-td');
            td_2.parent("success");
    }
```

I have added lists this way, but adding a row to a table doesn't seem to work out.

Comment: Could you please post a [mcve], or better yet a link to a CodePen or a JSFiddle running your code?

Answer (score 0):

According to the P5 reference, the parent method accepts a string ID, not a class name.
https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element

I believe you have to add an ID "success" to your table row instead of a class.

```
tr.id("success");
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it with pure JavaScript.

```
// Displaying data
    var table = document.getElementById("user_table");
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        var row = table.insertRow(i);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell2.innerHTML = player_data[i][0];
        cell3.innerHTML = player_data[i][1];
    }
```

Comment: name the cell variables correctly in line 7 and 8, its cell1 and cell2