# How to add a row to a p5 data table?

Tags: processing, p5.js

[The made this question because the only related question I was able to find appears to be completely unhelpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44783408/how-to-add-a-table-row-with-p5-js)

Let's say I have an empty p5 data table:

```
  data = new p5.Table();
  data.columns = ['x','y']
```

How do I add data to this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that [can be found on the docs](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Table/addRow) is as follows:

```
let newRow = data .addRow();
newRow.setNum('x', 12);
newRow.setString('name', 'cool string');
```

I wonder if anybody knows a direct way by adding paramaters to the `addRow` function?